# Determining the size of the next UDP datagram in system's queue

Tags: c++, c, windows, udp, winsock

I want to know the size of the next UDP datagram in the system's queue.

I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502203/can-boostasio-only-receive-full-udp-datagrams) with a similar doubt, but using boost. The last answer (as of 2010/09/23) say something about using `getsockopt` with the `SO_NREAD` option in OS X, but I can't find anything about this with Windows (using Winsock).

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms738573(VS.85).aspx) I found that I can use `ioctlsocket` with `FIONREAD` to find out what is the size of the entire queue, but I didn't find anything about the first datagram.

So my question is: 
**Is there a way to determine what is the size of the next UDP datagram in the queue using the sockets API?** (I'm not using boost).

I want my code to look like this:

```
char BigBuffer[ 64 * 1024 ];
void Read( void *Buf, size_t Size ) {
    size_t LengthInQueue = WhatTheSizeOfTheNextDatagram();
    if( Size < LengthInQueue ) {
         recvfrom( Socket, BigBuffer, 64*1024,  /*...*/ );
         memcpy( Buf, BigBuffer, Size );
    }
    else {
         recvfrom( Socket, Buf, size,  /*...*/ );
    }
}
```

I left out error checking and some parameters for the sake of space and readability.
I want to avoid copying to a intermediary buffer when its not needed.

Comment: Why do you want to do this? A UDP datagram is always under 64K. Surely you can just provide a 64K buffer in Windows?

Comment: I am trying to avoid a buffer copy in a read function.

Comment: on plain BSD sockets/POSIX/friends, it is often accomplished by using `recvfrom()` with `MSG_PEEK` flag: that is to read out header, calculate how many bytes are in the full message and then finally read the whole message. Otherwise, if this is real-world UDP where IP fragmentation is disabled, UDP datagram can't be more the 9200 bytes, the max size of the jumbo frame (because CRC16 of TCP/UDP doesn't *scale* above 9200 bytes).

Comment: Note that paying the cost of an extra system call to avoid a small copy may not actually be a win.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, you just want to ensure that `Buf` doesn't overflow, but you don't care about any extra data beyond `Size`, since you're discarding it anyway. In that case, all you need is this:

```
recvfrom( Socket, Buf, size,  /*...*/ );
```

The remainder of the packet is automatically discarded.

Quoted from [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms740120%28VS.85%29.aspx):

> For message-oriented sockets, data is extracted from the first enqueued message, up to the size of the buffer specified. If the datagram or message is larger than the buffer specified, the buffer is filled with the first part of the datagram, and recvfrom generates the error WSAEMSGSIZE. For unreliable protocols (for example, UDP) the excess data is lost.

Comment: As far as I know, there isn't a direct way to do this. I guess the rationale behind this is that UDP packets are usually of a fixed length specified by the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

You can `pop` this datagram and calculate lenght of this, for get datagram existence information you can use `select` function, and for get all datagram you can use `recv_from` function with 64k buffer size agrument, then this function was result what you want.

Comment: I think what Svisstack is getting at is something like boost::asio's message_peek ability, this lets you look at data without removing it from the queue. http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_37_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/s
ocket_base/message_peek.html 
Not sure where he is getting the terminology from though.

Comment: I can use a `recvfrom` with MSG_PEEK, but it will copy the buffer and then it would need to be copied again to remove it from the queue.

Answer (score 0):

Call ioctl (ioctlsocket on windows) function with FIONREAD:

```
#ifdef WIN32
    if(ioctlsocket(socket, FIONREAD, &ul) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
        return -1;
    }
    return (int)ul;
#else
    int i; // ?? int ??
    if(ioctl(socket, FIONREAD, &i) == -1) {
            return -1;
    }
    return i;
#endif
```

Comment: according to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738573(v=vs.85).aspx), if I have 2 (or more) outstanding messages to be read, FIONREAD will return the total size of them all instead of the size if the first message in the queue.

Answer (score 0):

The trick to this is to use

```
ssize_t len = recv(sockfd, NULL, 0, MSG_PEEK | MSG_TRUNC);
```

This will truncate the datagram to 0 bytes, so nothing is copied and the NULL buffer isn't dereferenced (nothing in the specs says this is OK but it would be wrong for any implementation to dereference the buffer as that would be a buffer overflow and undefined behavior. A 1 char buffer might be better if you are paranoid.). But thanks to `MSG_TRUNK` the return value will be the original size of the datagram, which is what we were after.

You can then use

```
char *buf = malloc(len);
len = recv(sockfd, buf, len, 0);
```

And don't forget to *check all return values for errors*.

PS: unless your datagrams are large (>4k or so) copying the message will be faster than the extra syscall.